# Multiple webservers using PHP files stored on only one server?

Tags: php, web-server, load-balancing

Is it possible to have multiple webserver nodes that are balanced by a load balancer use PHP files stored elsewhere on the local network? Right now, I have two nodes and static content (uploads, file caching) are shared via SSHFS. However, maintaining this setup is painful because the application exists locally on both servers. If I imagine another server or decide I need to balance another application, then that increases my workload by n+1 in managing these application files.

I can't find any resources on this problem. Is there a way to have .php application files stored on Server Z while Server X and Y run them using their own hardware?

Comment: are you trying to `include` a file from remote server?

Comment: No, I need it so that Nginx can point a request to a directory that is remote and have the scripts execute locally.

Comment: so you mean `include`, look into `allow_url_include`

Comment: Remote, but mountable locally? Within the same network though on a different machine? Either way, what you describe is possible. Another avenue to consider is lsync to replicate your static content and php files across to each webserver.

Comment: SSHFS hints Linux-family OS, and that's the only information about it. Because the solution can be OS-specific, you should provide more information about your entire environment.

Answer (score 0):

In our case, we have 2(or more) web servers and each has a copy of our application (we use GitHub tagging and the servers are instructed via DevOps to pull the tags). This way, each server has the same code base. If I need a new server, DevOps spins up a new instance, configures it and pulls a copy of the code. Add to the load balancer and go.

We have a separate instance running our DB and our DevOps server hosts a share via NFS. PHP sessions are stored in the DB and then loaded into memcached on DevOps server.

In your case you could set up a NFS share and have the other servers use that share to host files from. This is less efficient but doable.